# Mouse with continuous scrolling

Tags: wireless, mice

I am looking for a wireless mouse that has continuous scroll. Mostly i find wheels that have a discrete movement and are not sensible to small turns in the scroll. I would like that even an small amount of change in the scroll wheel to result in a small scrolling in the display, and a smooth spinning wheel, free of this markdowns as well. How can i know if a mouse has this feature or not? what is the name of it?

I found this "infinite scroll" technology that probably does what i want but its not exactly the same, as far as i understood. Also the examples of such mice i've seen are Logitech G series, specifically G305, which people say have small size and wouldn't fit for me, although it seems to be not that small. I've also found that Logitech M510 has a wheel that moves "freely enough" but i'm not sure what this means exactly. So i'm looking for recommendations of a wireless mouse with this feature for big hands or some information that leads me to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logitech Wireless Performance Mouse MX (I own 3) has a physical button that turns "detents" on and off. When in the free running position, one slightly faster than normal flick of your finger will make the mousewheel spin for almost 20 seconds (i think they originally called this Hyperscroll, but can't find a reference to it now). It is a large mouse. Uses rechargeable or replaceable AA battery (for me a nice feature). A third party program allows even more settings than normal. Google "uberOptions".

The MX Master (version 1? Only tried a friends one) free-runs automatically when the mousewheel goes over a certain speed and reverts back to detented under that speed. It has a manual (non mechanical) override button too and from memory the speed threshold can be set. (called Magspeed). At the time I tried it (18+? months ago) the setting software was a new system and annoyingly dumbed down... they claimed they were going to add features, but I don't know the status now. Used a proprietary rechargeable battery, advantage longer use time, disadvantage you can't just pop another battery in when it dies on you.

Logitech has a "Smooth Scrolling" plugin for Firefox, but it didn't work well for me when I first tried it over 2 years ago (apparently conflicted with my 3D mouse). Also, apparently doesn't work with their gaming mice.

Note there's a setting in Windows for the amount of lines scrolled per wheel increment... I believe it's 3 by default, but you may prefer less by the sound of it.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is a very helpful answer. Something i think is odd is that nowadays (it seems)  just Logitech produces mice with such technology, is that right?

Comment: Seems the Performance Mouse is getting hard to acquire :-( . BTW, I have literally worn out 2 of the mouses microswitches (they start doubleclicking instead of singleclicking), which I then replaced with Omron D2F-01 microswitches Element14 Part No 990-1949. (Originals were: Omron D2FC-F-7N (10M))

Comment: The MX Master 2 also has this facility to switch the detent on or off [with various modes - auto/manual/fixed] Many modern mice use light-sensing control which actually only sense as each 'window' passes the sensor, & each window has its own detent, so you don't actually get finer delineation than 'one window' whatever it's set to, though the control panel software can interpolate this at different rates.

Comment: Only Logitech sells these smooth scrolling mice because they have a patent on them, one that's pretty damn expensive from what I understand.

Comment: @Tetsujin i noticed that, in practice it makes the smooth scroll to have a small dead zone, but it doesn't bother me.

Comment: With further research after Stax's answer, I ended up buying Logitech M720, it is very comfortable, does everything i want (and more) and is cheaper then MX3.